# how to check memory limits

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

I am trying to check if the memory limits in my OS works. So I am using this is simple c program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const size_t GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    const size_t mem = 1 * GB;
    std::cout << "allocating " << mem << " bytes" << std::endl;
    void* p = malloc(mem);
    if (p) { std::cout << "memory allocated" << std::endl; }
    else { std::cout << "cannot allocate memory" << std::endl; }
    char a;
    std::cin >> a;
    free(p);
}
```

I am compiling with `-O0` but when I look to the performance monitor I see that my `a.out` is using only 128Kb. Why I don't see 1 GB?

Comment: Because you don't *really* use all of the allocated memory. Start writing to random locations in it and you will see some changes.

Comment: ...And to expand on the comment from @VoidPointer, use `new` and `delete` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And if he were to use `calloc`?

Comment: The O.S. will only reserve that memory area for you, so another programs cannot write inside it. But it is just reserved memory, you need to write in it to actually use this memory.

Comment: If you want to check the OS memory limits (and that OS is Windows), I suggest you Mark Russinovich blog entries: [Pushing the Limits of Windows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)

Comment: yes, it allocates memory if I fill it. But why I cannot allocate 2GB?

Comment: ok, I have to use `size_t` instead of `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit the memory. As long as you only reserve it you have allocated "virtual memory". You commit with reading or writing the memory. With your program just add

```
void* p = malloc(mem);
if (p) { 
    std::cout << "memory allocated" << std::endl;
    memset(p, 0, mem);
} else {
    std::cout << "cannot allocate memory" << std::endl; }
```

In the Windows operating system you can use the function `VirtualQuery` to see what chunks of memory are reserved and what is committed.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will only "use" the memory that you are actually touching, so it will not show on performance monitor or such like when unless you actually "use" the memory. This is because some applications allocate large amounts of memory "just in case", and it would take a lot of extra time to ACTUALLY populate that memory into the process, when in fact it isn't being used.